# Vote Counter Error

Tags: java, swing

My instructor gave us code for 2 classes. One setting a `JFrame` and another set with class for making a red button and counting how many times its been pressed. He wants us to add code to make a blue button, edit program to count how many times red button and the blue button has been pressed individually. Then he also wants us to add a message; like say if red is winning, he wants us to add a statement to the `JFrame` red is winning, along with blue winning or a tie. Code is below, please aid me!

```
//*********************************************************
// VoteCounter.java
//
// Demonstrates a graphical user interface and event
// listeners to tally votes for two candidates, Red and Blue.
// [modified from a lab assignment in the Lewis/Loftis lab manual]
//*********************************************************


import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class VoteCounter
{
    //----------------------------------------------
    // Creates the main program frame.
    //----------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vote Counter");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new VoteCounterPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}



public class VoteCounterPanel extends JPanel
{
    private int votesForRed;
    private JButton red;
    private JLabel labelRed;
    //**********************
    //Added Blue Varriables
    //**********************
    private int votesForBlue;
    private JButton blue;
    private JLabel labelBlue;
    //************************
    //Added Winner Varriables
    //************************
    private int Winning;
    private JLabel labelWinning;

    private int vote;


    //----------------------------------------------
    // Constructor: Sets up the GUI.
    //----------------------------------------------
    public VoteCounterPanel()
    {
        votesForRed = 0;
        red = new JButton("Vote for Red");
        red.addActionListener(new VoteButtonListener());
        labelRed = new JLabel("Votes for Red: " + votesForRed);

        add(red);
        add(labelRed);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        //***************************************************
        // Represents a listener for button push (action) events
        //***************************************************

        votesForBlue = 0;
        blue = new JButton("Vote for Blue");
        blue.addActionListener(new VoteButtonListener());
        labelBlue = new JLabel("Votes for Blue: " + votesForBlue);

        add(blue);
        add(labelBlue);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 70));
        setBackground(Color.cyan);

        //******************************************************
        //Added code for winning
        //******************************************************

        if(votesForBlue > votesForRed)
        {
           labelWinning = new JLabel("Blue is winning");

           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
           setBackground(Color.cyan);
        }
        else if(votesForRed > votesForBlue)
        {
           labelWinning = new JLabel("Red is winning");

           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
           setBackground(Color.cyan);
        }
        else
        {
           labelWinning = new JLabel("It's a tie");

           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
           setBackground(Color.cyan);
        }
    }


    private class VoteButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //----------------------------------------------
        // Updates the appropriate vote counter when a 
        // button is pushed for one of the candidates.
        //----------------------------------------------
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            vote = ActionEvent;

            if()
            {
                votesForRed++;
                labelRed.setText("Votes for Red: " + votesForRed);
            }
            else
            {
                votesForBlue++;
                labelBlue.setText("Votes for Blue: " + votesForBlue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: The "who's winning" logic is in the constructor, where it will only be called once, updating the "who's winning" display elements before any user input is taken (and never updating those elements after input is accepted)

Comment: Oh sorry :P Two errors, one, the counter on the blue and red button both add at the same time, tried adding a if else statement but I am unfamiliar with actionListener. Second, I cant get the "who is winning" message to display

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor, you have conditional logic to show who's winning.  The problem is that constructors are ran before any user input can be accepted; so, that logic is not going to be dynamically called.

Move the logic to show who is winning into the `actionPerformed`, in such a way that you update the vote counts and then check to see if you need to change the "who's winning" display elements.

--- Edited for update ---

As far as the "they both update" error, that's probably because you are updating both counters in your `actionPerformed` method.  Odds are you want to "read" some field out of your action, and only update one.

Currently the code you have pasted will not compile because empty conditionals are not permitted in Java; so, I imagine that whatever you last complied on your end handled the action by incrementing both the red and blue counters.